# Get single column from using asp.net mvc ExecuteStoreQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to return top 1 `CustomerId` from my table like this:

```
string nxtCustId = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("SELECT TOP 1 CustId FROM CustomerMaster WHERE Id >=(SELECT Max(Id) FROM CustomerDetail ) ORDER BY Id ").ToString();
```

But it returns `System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult1[System.String]`
I want to do it with only `ExecuteStoreQuery` OR `ExecuteStoreCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string nxtCustId = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>(
    "SELECT TOP 1 CustId FROM CustomerMaster WHERE Id >=(SELECT Max(Id) FROM CustomerDetail ) ORDER BY Id ")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Having said that, don't create "IDs" this way; it's not multi-user safe. Use an autoincrement field or a generator/sequence.